# How to resolve this redirect conflict in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website in which I am using this code in root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works fine until WordPress is installed later.

I installed WordPress in `/blog` part of the website. `/blog` directory has it's own `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I believe WordPress installation is affecting my global apache rules. I want to redirect all my `www.mysite.com/blog/my-blog-post` to `mysite.com/blog/my-blog-post`

Comment: Have you tried adding the `non-www` as an `alias` in the apache config for the virtual host, rather than the `.htaccess`? Your `.htaccess` shouldn't be an issue, and if you remove the 301 from the root `.htaccess` then you know it won't be conflicting as the only `.htaccess` will be the one in the WP directory. Does that sorta make sense?!

Comment: Where is that apache config setting? I'm on a shared hosting plan.

Comment: That would be in your virtual host config [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts](See This). What web server are you using? LAMP, Xampp etc.

Comment: Shared hosting at godaddy. Plus the link you gave is broken.

Comment: Ahh, looks like i mis-formatted it in the reply. That's okay, that means you don't that link :) If you speak to GoDaddy, and say you want your www and non www domain to be on your hosting account, they'll be able to help. From there, you can remove the htaccess doing the 301 and it may fix the issues you're having

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Apache 2.3.10` and above then you can use [`InheritBefore`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Otherwise on older Apache versions you need to include `www` removal rule in current .htaccess as well like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: It's defective, `www.mysite.com/blog/` redirects me to `mysite.com`. But it should redirect to `mysite.com/blog/`

Comment: Which one of these 2 options have you tried. Btw your root .htaccess should also be updated with the `www` removal rule as shown above in my answer.